# Apache HttpClient not sending proxy authentication credentials

Tags: java, httpclient, apache-httpclient-4.x, solrj

I'm using SolrJ 4.7.2 and HttpClient 4.3.1 and running into a few difficulties with proxy authentication.

I am using the below code to proxy through one server to a separate Solr instance. The proxy code is working as expected however when I enable basic authentication, it does not appear to be sending across any credentials to the proxy. I've tried every possible combination of properties I can think of but have hit a brick wall. Any help would be much appreciated!

```
RequestConfig requestConfig = RequestConfig.custom()
    .setConnectTimeout(this.connectionTimeout)
    .setConnectionRequestTimeout(this.connectionTimeout)
    .setSocketTimeout(this.connectionTimeout)
    .build();

HttpClientBuilder httpClientBuilder = HttpClients.custom()
    .setDefaultRequestConfig(requestConfig)
    .setMaxConnTotal(128)
    .setMaxConnPerRoute(32)
    .disableRedirectHandling();

HttpHost proxy = new HttpHost(proxyUrl, proxyPort, proxyProtocol);
DefaultProxyRoutePlanner routePlanner = new DefaultProxyRoutePlanner(proxy);
CredentialsProvider credentialsProvider = new BasicCredentialsProvider();
credentialsProvider.setCredentials(
    new AuthScope(proxyUrl, proxyPort, AuthScope.ANY_REALM, "basic"),
    new UsernamePasswordCredentials(proxyUsername, proxyPassword));

httpClientBuilder
    .setDefaultCredentialsProvider(credentialsProvider)
    .setTargetAuthenticationStrategy(new ProxyAuthenticationStrategy())
    .setRoutePlanner(routePlanner);

CloseableHttpClient httpClient = httpClientBuilder.build();


HttpSolrServer solrServer = new HttpSolrServer(baseUrl, httpClient);
```

Comment: Please do not do #setTargetAuthenticationStrategy(new ProxyAuthenticationStrategy()). This is not going to help. Consider running your app with HttpClient context / wire logging turned on and posting the log (with sensitive stuff like passwords removed)